# Pass prop value to child, based on parent width in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I'm working on a board component that have `n x n` number of square components. I want to set the square sizes based on the board width, somthing like `board.offsetWidth / boardCols`.

How can I pass the square size, or the parents width, to the child?

The parent width is set to 0.5vh so I can't know the width of the board,  in pixels, until the component is mounted, but the props are passed before mounted.

Here is the parent component:

```
<template>
  <div ref="board" class="board">
    <square-component :square-size="squareSize" v-for="square in rows*cols"></square-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
//I'm working on Nuxt, no imports needed
const board = ref()
const props = defineProps({
  cols: {type: Number, default: 10},
  rows: {type: Number, default: 10},
})

const squareSize = computed(() => {
  //here, board value is undefined
  const squareSize = board.value.offsetWidth / props.rows
  return squareSize
})
</script>

<style>
.board {
  width: .5vh
}
</style>
```

And here is the child:

```
<template>
  <div :style=[sizeStyle, myOtherComputedStyles]></div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  squareSize: {type: Number, required: true}
})

const sizeStyle = computed(() => {
  return {
    width: `${props.squareSize}px`
    height: `${props.squareSize}px`
  }
})
</script>
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

We can change `squareSize` from `computed` to `ref(0)` and create `ResizeObserver` in `onMounted()` to change and watch it. At that time `board.value` will be a proper DOM element:

```
<script setup>

import {ref, computed, onMounted} from 'vue';
import squareComponent from './square-component.vue';

const board = ref(), squareSize = ref(0);
const props = defineProps({
  cols: {type: Number, default: 10},
  rows: {type: Number, default: 10},
});

onMounted(() => new ResizeObserver(() => squareSize.value = board.value.offsetWidth / props.rows).observe(board.value));

</script>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explantion.

Comment: @Miguel i've improved the code by using `ResizeObserver`. The window's resize event is async and looking not good not resizing the cells immediately.